# Moq and setting up DB Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, entity-framework-core, moq

I have an Entity Framework DB Context file.
I am trying to setup a Moq framework in NUnit. Currently receiving error below for Moq Nunit test. How would I setup the DBContext, and add items to a Product Table?

"No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext."

**Electronics DB Context file**

```
public partial class ElectronicsContext : DbContext
{
    public ElectronicsContext()
    {
    }

    public ElectronicsContext(DbContextOptions<ElectronicsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategory { get; set; }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    var connection = @"Server=localhost;Database=Electronics;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
    services.AddDbContext<ElectronicsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

**Moq Nunit Test**

```
 [SetUp]
 public void Setup()
 {
    var ElectronicsContext = new Mock<ElectronicsContext>();
    var ProductRepository = new Mock<ProductRepository>();

    Product producttest = new Product();
    _dbContext.Product.Add(new Product {ProductId = 1, ProductName = "TV", ProductDescription = "TV testing",ImageLocation = "test"});
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: this should help you out:  https://mirkomaggioni.com/2017/08/30/ef-db-context-mock-with-moq/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to mock the context in unit tests. You should use the `DbContextOptions` class to specify you want to use an in memory database to run your tests against.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestProducts()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Products Test")
        .Options;

    using(var context = new ElectronicsContext(options))
    {
        context.Products.Add(new Product {ProductId = 1, ProductName = "TV", ProductDescription = "TV testing",ImageLocation = "test"});
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    using(var context = new ElectronicsContext(options))
    {
        // run your test here

    }
}
```

This runs against the in-memory representation of your database instead of relying on the physical server. The connection string you provided in the `startup.cs` is not used as part of the tests.

More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests)

Comment: You don't want to do that because the in-memory database will persist for all of your tests. If you read the link I gave you, there is a line that states `Each test method specifies a unique database name, meaning each method has its own InMemory database.`  Best practice is to use the test method name as the database name for each test

Comment: quick question, when should I use Moq then for db testing?

Comment: If you can do all your tests using the InMemoryDatabase then you probably don't need Moq for the db testing, but it depends on your architecture.

Comment: yeah, I Just wanted to know for the sake of it

Comment: One of the main benefits of mocking instead of InMemory is the ability to guarantee that an Exception will be thrown.