# Data type for DbContextOptionsBuilder in NUnit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, nunit, moq

I am trying to locate the data type for DbContextOptionsBuilder.

I have an Entity Framework DBContext file. I setup an InMemory database with NUnit.  How can I set this up without var? I know its best practice to have a clean database for each test, but just trying to learn, and have a database for multiple tests.

**Electronics DBContext File**

```
public partial class ElectronicsContext : DbContext
{
    public ElectronicsContext()
    {
    }

    public ElectronicsContext(DbContextOptions<ElectronicsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategory { get; set; }
```

**NUnit Test**

```
public class TestClass
{

[SetUp]
public void TestProducts()
{

   // This Works
   // var context = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
   //     .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "ProductsTest")
   //     .Options;

   // This does not work
    DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext> context = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "ProductsTest")
        .Options;
```

When Running this: I receive error below, however it works other way [Moq and setting up DB Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810039/moq-and-setting-up-db-context)

```
    [Test]
    public void TestProducts()
    {
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext> context = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()

        context.Product.Add(new Product { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "TV", ProductDescription = "TV testing", ImageLocation = "test" });
        context.SaveChanges();

Error: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>' does not contain a definition for 'Product' and no accessible extension method 'Product' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: `DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext> context` should be `DbContextOptions` as you assigning the `.Options` at the end, isn't it? Look at the second question you have asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810039/moq-and-setting-up-db-context...

Comment: ok, thanks it worked, do you know by any chance? started programming last month,  I thought I was instantiating it as DbContextOptionsBuilder,

Comment: C# is static/strongly-typed however they have `var` as they call it syntactic sugar. This is just a shortcut provided by the language to reduce the amount of code in some common situations...

Comment: yeah, I know that, just wondering why it worked as DbContextOptions, but not as DbContextOptionsBuilder, when we are instantiating it as a new DbContextOptionsBuilder..

Comment: oh well, I'll figure it out, something new people are always trying to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign object of the type `DbContextOptions` to variable of the type `DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>`. Look at the last line of the assignment, you have `.Options;`

```
// This does not work
DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext> context = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "ProductsTest")
    .Options;
```

As C# is static/strongly-typed it is not allowed and the compiler will complain about it. However starting from c# 3.0 `var` is introduced. It is nothing else than syntactic sugar, the shortcut provided by the language to reduce amount of the code that have to be written in some common situations.

Your example is one of the examples where you are encouraged to use `var`, compare the lenght of the lines and readability...

**Without `var`**

```
DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext> context = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
```

**With `var`**

```
var context = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
```

Comment: ok, I will have to read up what .options does to the data type, I am guessing it converts DbContextOptionsBuilder to DbContextOptions

Comment: 2 tips for you, builder pattern and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder ;)

Comment: added comment above, just had time to retest,